# How to derivate the arc length of manifold curve？

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, curves, arc-length

I would like to find the arc length of a manifold $a\left( \theta  \right)$. The manifold can be regarded as a curve embedded in an N-dimensional complex space.

The manifold is given as
$a\left( \theta  \right) = {e^{-jr\pi \sin \theta }} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{e^{-j\pi \sin \theta }}}\\
{{e^{-j2\pi \sin \theta }}}\\
 \vdots \\
{{e^{-jN\pi \sin \theta }}}
\end{array}} \right]$ , and $r = {\left[ {1,2, \cdots ,N} \right]^T}$.

The related reference defines the arc length s as
$s = \int_0^\theta  {\left\| {\frac{{da\left( \theta  \right)}}{{d\theta }}} \right\|d\theta } $, and the result is given as $s\left( \theta  \right) = \pi \left\| r \right\|\left( {1 - \cos \theta } \right)$.

The problem is that I know little about differential geometry, and I don't know how to derivate the above formulation. I need help with the derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a differential geometry question, but you don't need differential geometry to solve it. Just apply the definition
$$ \left\|{da(\theta) \over d\theta}\right\| = \sqrt{ {da(\theta) \over d\theta} \cdot \overline{da(\theta) \over d\theta}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N {da_i(\theta) \over d\theta}\overline{da_i(\theta) \over d\theta}}$$
and you'll get a simple expression for the integrand that you can then integrate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved it with your indication.